box-shadow moves off-center when input changes position on page
I added a simple centered box-shadow to inputs, to highlight when they had issues. These inputs are inside a flexbox-based grid, i.e., flex rows with columns inside. Some column parts show hidden children when hovered (:hover), and this display can change the height of their row. This is intentional. Of course, this pushes the rows below it down and up.
The problem: this movement pushes the inputs' new box-shadows off-center. When a row gets resized, or after it returns to normal height, the box-shadow on below inputs might not return to their normal position. Hovering or interacting the inputs will re-center their box-shadow.
Expected: the box-shadow stays centered on the inputs, regardless of their position on the page.
Reality: when inputs are moved, the box-shadows sometimes shift up or down by a pixel. Even left-right if containers are resized horizontally.
Testing/observations: When creating a MRE, I have noticed it is generally caused by fractional heights or resizing. In my project, I have specified some heights and padding in rem or em rather than px.
Any combination of the following properties in the MRE can trigger the sub-pixel position problems, in their own ways:

height with em-based sizing
padding with em-based sizing
font-size with em-based sizing
scrollbars
horizontal resizing of parent container(s)

My project doesn't have a resize container; this is here to easily simulate resizing the whole window.



MRE (has combinations of the above properties to better simulate my project's actual layout):


.resize-container {
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* resizing can affect x and y position */
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.hover-part {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: lavender;

  & > .extra {
    display: none;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    /* fractions of pixels (em) affecting it */
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  }
}

.hover-part:hover {
  /* fractions of pixels (em) affecting it */
  min-height: 2.6em;
  /* scroll can affect it */
  overflow-y: auto;

  & > .extra {
    display: block;
  }
}

.input-part > input {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px red;
}
<div class="resize-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 1. Hover here to resize height</span>
      <div class="extra">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        123456789009876543211234567890098765432112345678900987654321
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 2. Hover here to resize height</span>
      <div class="extra">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 3. Hover here to resize height</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 4. Hover here to resize height</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I would rather not have to convert these em-based heights to px, unless it's the only fix. I prefer em-based proportions when dealing with text elements for the font size responsiveness.
This behavior is happening in Firefox version 124.0.1 (64-bit). I am also using a 2k resolution large monitor. This behavior does not happen in Chrome version 123.
Edit: I'm using Windows 10, and my monitor resolution is scaled at 100%. Here is a JSFiddle as the styling on SO looks slightly different.
And here is an example image of the behavior I'm seeing: box-shadow offset

Look into "sub-pixel rounding". Your calculated page rendering and your monitor don't always agree, but the do the best they can to get along.

@isherwood Thank you! I've added a jsfiddle and an image of what I am seeing. I think SO's styling masks the issue more than other places. I'm on Win10, res. at 100%, but that doesn't dismiss it. I will look into sub-pixel rounding as well.

I discovered that Firefox's default form element styling - especially the default border - appears to be affecting or causing it. When I specify an explicit border (or any other style relating to it), it forces the default browser styling to change/disappear, and the random off-center behavior disappears.
Here's one simple way my MRE can be fixed, by adding
input {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}



.resize-container {
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* resizing can affect x and y position */
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.hover-part {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: lavender;

  & > .extra {
    display: none;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    /* fractions of pixels (em) affecting it */
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  }
}

.hover-part:hover {
  /* fractions of pixels (em) affecting it */
  min-height: 2.6em;
  /* scroll can affect it */
  overflow-y: auto;

  & > .extra {
    display: block;
  }
}

.input-part > input {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px red;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
<div class="resize-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 1. Hover here to resize height</span>
      <div class="extra">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        123456789009876543211234567890098765432112345678900987654321
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 2. Hover here to resize height</span>
      <div class="extra">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 3. Hover here to resize height</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hover-part">
      <span>Row 4. Hover here to resize height</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



